# Blender Game Engine Python

Tags: python, blender

at first sorry for my bad english, i´m from germany ^^

I have a little problem with my own written Pythonscript.
I´d like to have a flickering light so i put in a Spotlight,
this one i give two Property´s:

1. ***Boolean named toggleProp***
2. ***Integer named timer***

I linked three logic bricks to the spotlight, an Alwayssensor that´s set so level triggering true, linked to a Pythonbrick where i put in my script and than linked to a Poperty Brick where i set the mode to toggle an linked my Property´s.

I wrote following lines in my Pythonscript:

```
import bge


def main():

    cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
    light = cont.owner

    toggleProp = cont.actuators ["toggleProp"]

    if light ["timer"] == 25:
        cont.activate(toggleProp)
        light ["timer"] = 0

    if light ["toggle"] == False:
        light.energy = 0.200
    else:
        light.energy = 1.500

    light ["timer"] += 1


main()
```

when i start my game, nothing happens.
The console says: **ImportError: No module named 'bge'**

i´m using Blender version 2.78.

Thanks and best regards from germany :)

Comment: are you running the script in the blender scripting interface or somewhere else?

Comment: You may find you have better luck at blender.stackexchange.com

Comment: You should only get that error if you run the script in blender's text editor. You don't need to run the script just start the game engine and the logic bricks will run the script as needed. Is `Blender Game` selected at the top of the window or does it say `Blender Render` or `Cycles Render`?

Answer (score 0):

Not easy to do "import bge" directly from an native python script until you compile Blender to support this specific option (take also in consideration that this option is no more followed by the dev team) ...

But ... you may run you script directly from Blender (under OSX/Linux Blender need to be run from a terminal.),

To do this : 
Select "Text Editor" in Blender then paste the following 2 lines in the text field,

```
filename = "/path/to/your/python_script/run.py"
exec(compile(open(filename).read(), filename, 'exec'))
```

Adapt the path according to your need, then run it from Blender using a mouse click on the "Run Script" button.

More information [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_59_2/info_tips_and_tricks.html)